# Why custom shipping method called twice?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, magento-community

I am trying to create my custom shipping method everything is okay but I see that magento is calling  my collectRates function twice

I wasn't able to figure why magento doing this

I had tried to test it on fresh installation of magento and same case happen

any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `collectRates()` methods gets called every time when Magento recalculates the quote totals. Magento recaculates the totals whenever it thinks the totals may have changed.

E.g. when checking out with one shipping methode enabled (vanilla installation), `collectRates()` is executed when

- when the entered shipping address is saved (starting at `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveShippingAction()`)
- when the selected payment method is saved (starting at `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction()`)

Both the shipping address and the payment method can have effects on the total amount and totals of the order.